Error while trying to install x-org via rpm pkg using alien
I am currently using AMD Ryzen 5500 U CPU and am new to using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS ,the installation of
Ubuntu was a bit tricky as i had to edit the grub config and set it to nomodeset in order to boot up the distro . Later when I tried to open Ubuntu in xorg rather  thanxwayland the screen blacked out and redirected to login page again , So currently facing issues while installing x-org(11-x) and related services.
$ sudo apt install xorg
[sudo] password for aadithya: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
xorg is already the newest version (1:7.7+23ubuntu3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up xorg-x11-server (1.20.11-25) ...
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
chown: invalid group: ‘mockbuild:mock’
dpkg: error processing package xorg-x11-server (--configure):
 installed xorg-x11-server package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xorg-x11-server

I am also getting similar error while

trying to remove( sudo apt autoremove ) the failed installation.
2)sudo apt-get install xauth
please assist me solve this problem


That's strange - I've only come across mock/mockbuild in relation to RPM packaging, for example How to eliminate the warnings: mockbuild does not exist. Have you been experimenting with using / repackaging RPMs?

... in addition, xorg-x11-server doesn't appear to be an Ubuntu package name (but is a RedHat package name)

@steeldriver I tried installing rpm pkg  using alien and it failed , xorg-x11-server-1.20.11-24.el8_10.src.rpm from https://oraclelinux.pkgs.org/8/ol8-appstream-aarch64/xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.11-24.el8_10.aarch64.rpm.html

is there some way to revert things back

I suggest you [edit] your question (including the title) to reflect what you did - hopefully it will catch the eye of someone with relevant experience

Why are you doing it this convoluted way? You can install xorg from the Ubuntu repos. This sounds like an X Y problem.

thank you so much  @steeldriver for directing me the right way . Just uninstall the xorg-x11-server using synaptic package manager and that help me resolve the issue .

@OrganicMarble i did not know that it was available in Ubuntu repos  and thought x-11 and x-org and 2 completely different things and it needed separate installation.

From a number year of experience; don't install anything else except *.deb -packages with dpkg, apt, synaptic  or similar. You will generally be happier if any trouble arises. (Personally, I even purged snap, and avoid flatpack, but have adopted AppImage)
